# Matlab Lsim MIMO system error

Tags: matlab

i'am following a course in flight dynamics and i want to plot the respons of a step input (of 0.01745) at one of the 4 inputs.
I have 4 inputs: 
u,w,q,theta

however, i get an error:
Error using DynamicSystem/lsim (line 98)
When simulating the response to a specific
input signal, the input data U must be a matrix
with as many rows as samples in the time vector
T, and as many columns as input channels.

as far as i see in my workspace i meet those requirments...
My code does work when i use u=ones(size(t)), but this gives a step input on all 4 channels u,w,q,theta.... Can you please help me? thanks :)

```
    clear all; clc;


A=[ 0.00501 0.00464 -72.90 -31.34;
    -0.08570 -0.545 309 -7.4;
    0.00185 -0.00767 -0.395 0.00132;
    0 0 1 0];

B=[5.63 -23.8 -4.51576 0]'; 

C=[1 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0;
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];

D=0;

sys=ss(A,B,C,D);
t=0:0.1:1000;

%definieer initial conditions: 
u0=0;
w0=0;
q0=0;
theta0=0;
x0=[u0 w0 q0 theta0]';

u1=zeros(size(t));         %u
u2=zeros(size(t));         %w
u3=zeros(size(t));         %q
u4=zeros(size(t))+0.01745; %theta0
u=[u1;u2;u3;u4]'; **% this line gives the error**

%u=zeros(size(t)); **%this works but gives step input at all 4 inputs...**

figure(1)
subplot(1,2,1)
lsim(sys,u,t,x0)
xlabel('time');
ylabel('theta (rad)                                  q (rad/s)                            w (ft/s)                               u (ft/s)');
subplot(1,2,2)
pzmap(sys)
title('pole-zere map A-7A corsair II, ex 6.1');

damp(sys)%geeft eigenvalue,damping,freq
[U,D]=eig(A);
eigenvector=U;

disp('----------------------------------------')
disp('magnitude, welke mode is het sterkst voor (u,w,q,theta)')
disp('   |short-period mode |    phugoid mode|')
EigenvecMagnitude=abs(U);
EigenvecMagnitude
disp('----------------------------------------')
```

Comment: zeros(n) gives an nxn matrix do you want zeros(n, 1)? I haven't checked in detail but that doesn't seem right currently.

Comment: @nivag that doesn't apply since the OP is using `size(t)`, which produces a 2-by-1 output for vectors, as input to `zeros`. So essentially equal to calling `zeros` with two input arguments.

Comment: @ mikkola you are right. As i said, the sizes of matrixes agree, altough matlab says it doesnt... It looks like matlab doesnt recognise the 4 inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`ss`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html) states the matrices relate to the following system model:

```
dx/dt = Ax(t) + Bu(t)
 y(t) = Cx(t) + Du(t)
```

and in particular that `B` "-- is an Nx-by-Nu real- or complex-valued matrix", where `Nx` is the state dimension (4 in your case) and `Nu` is the control dimension, which according to your `B=[5.63 -23.8 -4.51576 0]';` is 1.

However, when you attempt to use the matrix `u=[u1;u2;u3;u4]';` as presented in your code as a control input, that will fail since its dimensions are not as expected (4 instead of 1). The length of the control inputs (corresponding to `t`) seems to be ok in your code.

In conclusion, you need to modify *at least* `B` (mind you, I'm not an expert on the particular system -- you know it best yourself!) to make this work. Perhaps you need `Bnew = diag(B)` or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. I understand your point and indeed, when i convert B with diag(B) i dont get an error ha. However, my output doesnt make sense at all but we are getting somewhere :)

Comment: @JurriënPlijter Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

we consider a mimo 2x2 we would like to transmit symbol x1 trough the first antenna

it is possible to assign to symbol x1 two transmit power such as x1 sent trough channel h11 is p11

and x1 sent trough channel h21 is p21 ( are the value of p11 and p21 must be the same or different)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cLmS.jpg)?